# Private Git repo using Smart HTTP with LDAP authentification

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, git

I've been crawling the interwebz and getting my hands dirty for the last few days, but I can't seem to make it all work together.

I managed to get a HTTP repo working with Ubuntu 10.04 over Smart HTTP (pull and push over HTTP) for a single repo. This means that I do the initial setup over SSH to the server (`git init --bare`) and after that the clients can pull and push to it (`git clone http://servername/allgitrepos/repo.git`).

Unfortunately it's impossible to add a new repo without SSHing to the server and adding it manually) i.e. `git push http://servername/allgitrepos/repo2.git` (allgitrepos is available for everyone to read-write and execute) would fail talking about `git update-server-info` (which seems to be a general error message).

So far the repository is anonymous, so I would like to [authenticate using LDAP](http://linuxadminzone.com/how-to-setup-git-http-authentication-using-ldap-in-apache/) and **also use the LDAP creds to make the git commit**.

So, how can I push new repos to the server and how can I use the LDAP creds to make the git commit.

Thanks

**Edit 1**

1. Can it be done using git-remote?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `gitolite` might suit your needs.

I don't recall if it was available for 10.04 via `apt-get` but you can clone it (via `git` of course) from https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily achieve this. The git remote protocols don't have a way of creating repositories as a side effect of `git push`. You could write a wrapper around git that automatically creates repos when you try to push.

Comment: Ok. So I would have to set-up the basic layout of the repository on the server first. Then I guess users could add submodules.